# how to implement photo gallary with slide show

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I am developing a web application, I need a modern photo gallary using ajax or jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery you will have many options. But what i like the most is Galleriffic becuase it is customizable and quite trendy:
http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-2.html

Regards.

Comment: Well you won't find it specifically for asp.net.. but its easy to integrate it. Check this out: http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/index.html. you just have to create markup needed for this plugin..

Comment: are these open source software

Comment: jquery and its libraries are Generally GNU(GPL) and this library also offers you the code to modify and use it as you wish.

Comment: @shoaib i have an problem where my vs2008 dont provide an jquery

Answer (score 0):

use plugin

http://blarnee.com/wp/jquery-image-carousels-for-slidehow/

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/carousel3d